# How to backup a Windows system installation (no user data)

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup

I am a bit confused by the backup utilities in Windows 10, and a bit scared of the fact that Windows ships with 3 different utilities (as far as I can tell).

[image: system restore]
[image: backup]
[image: back up and restore]

What's the difference between System Restore, Backup and Back up and Restore (Windows 7)? I am looking for something like [timeshift on Linux](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift): I want to backup the whole system installation **except** the user data and application configuration (so basically everything except `C:\Users` I think. On Linux, `timeshift` backups up everything but `/home/` for instance, which includes user data and user application configuration files). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

System Restore periodically saves the state of Windows. It is a very good thing
to allow, as it can, in case of system corruption, to let you return to a healthy
state.

Other Windows backup utilities are to be avoided. Use a third-party solution.
You may find some reviews in the articles:

- [Best Free Drive Cloning Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm)
- [Best Free File-Based Backup Program](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hard-drive-backup-program.htm)

My personal favorite is AOMEI Backupper.